# Retrieving arguments from an SQL query

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to get all arguments from an SQL query. In this case the queries are the plain strings in an array. 
I have a lot of pairs of the queries in the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = ? AND t.attr2 = ?) OR t.attr3= ?
```

And its pair is (which contains the parameters what I want to retrieve):

```
SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = 3 AND t.attr2 = 'str') OR t.attr3= 4
```

So the output will be:

```
3, 'str' and 4.
```

How can I retrieve these values based on this pairs?

I tried with regex in Java but it can difficult, because the ? can be a number, 
a string and so on. The string can contain another ? which is the part of the string for example:

```
UPDATE my_table SET attr2 = ? WHERE attr5 = ?
UPDATE my_table SET attr2 = 'Is it true?' WHERE attr5 = 'What is it?'
```

Comment: If your queries are well formatted, you can search for `' ? '` -- that is spaces around the question mark.  In common writing, there would never be a space before the '?'.

Comment: May we ask what your starting point is?  Do you actually have a string with the parameters bound?  Or, is your starting point the first string which just has placeholders?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: He says he has both strings.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working script which uses basic Java regex pattern matching.  It works by performing two matches.  First, it looks up every column/alias being assigned to a `?` positional placeholder.  Then, for each matching column/alias, it does a second lookup against the query string with bound values.

```
String query1 = "SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = ? AND t.attr2 = ?) OR t.attr3= ?";
String query2 = "SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = 3 AND t.attr2 = 'str') OR t.attr3= 4";

String p1 = "([\\w.]+)\\s*=\\s*\\?(?=(([^']*'){2})*[^']*$)";
Pattern r1 = Pattern.compile(p1);
Matcher m1 = r1.matcher(query1);

// for each matching column/alias with a placeholder
while (m1.find()) {
    String p2 = m1.group(1) + "\\s*=\\s*([\\w.']+)";
    Pattern r2 = Pattern.compile(p2);
    Matcher m2 = r2.matcher(query2);

    // if we find it in the second query string, then print the value
    if (m2.find()) {
        System.out.println("Column: " + m1.group(1) + " has parameter value: " + m2.group(1));
    }
}

Column: t.attr1 has parameter value: 3
Column: t.attr2 has parameter value: 'str'
Column: t.attr3 has parameter value: 4
```

Note that I make a few assumptions here, including that matching columns would only have word characters (`\w`) plus dot, and that matching values would only involve word characters and single quotes (for string literals).  There are probably many edge cases for which the above code would fail, also depending your database and its particular syntax.  I am offering this an immediate solution to the problem you presented, and as a general approach which could be made to work.

Comment: Your script breaks if there's a question mark in one of the arguments.  https://repl.it/@robertwharvey/PeacefulDarkturquoiseMachinecodeinstruction

Comment: @RobertHarvey I presume your comment is getting at the possibility that `?` might occur inside a string literal in a different query, and that then my script would break.  I have added logic which should prevent such `?` as being positional parameters.

Comment: [Here is a working demo](https://rextester.com/KZEDD3649) which shows this edge case has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with this approach, where you replace every `?` with `(.*)` in your query, and then create a pattern based out of it. And then apply the other pair of string which has actual values and then print out the values in all the groups which will be dynamically created as per `?` present in the query string.

Here is a Java code doing the same.

```
// This map stores your paired queries where key stores the placeholder query and value stores the query having actual parameters.
Map<String, String> pairMap = new HashMap<>();
pairMap.put("SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = ? AND t.attr2 = ?) OR t.attr3= ?", "SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = 3 AND t.attr2 = 'str') OR t.attr3= 4");
pairMap.put("UPDATE my_table SET attr2 = ? WHERE attr5 = ?", "UPDATE my_table SET attr2 = 'Is it true?' WHERE attr5 = 'What is it?'");

pairMap.forEach((k,v) -> {
    System.out.println("For query: "+k);
    k = k.replaceAll("([*+^$()\\[\\]{}])", "\\\\$1"); // this escapes all the characters that have special meaning in regex so they get treated as literal characters
    k = k.replaceAll("\\?", "(.*)");

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(k);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(v);
    if (m.matches()) {
        for (int i=0;i<m.groupCount();i++) {
            System.out.println(m.group(i+1));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Didn't match");
    }
    System.out.println();
});
```

Which prints,

```
For query: SELECT * FROM my_table t WHERE (t.attr1 = ? AND t.attr2 = ?) OR t.attr3= ?
3
'str'
4

For query: UPDATE my_table SET attr2 = ? WHERE attr5 = ?
'Is it true?'
'What is it?'
```

As you can see the code, it works for any variable values of place holders `?` in the query string and prints all the values present in the paired query which has the actual values.